# Java richfaces calendar does not trigger action when it has incorrect data

Tags: java, jsp, ejb, richfaces

Java richfaces calendar does not trigger action when it has incorrect data:

I have this calendar:

```
<rich:calendar id="olr_from" enableManualInput="true"
                    isDayEnabled="isDayEnabled"
                    dayStyleClass="getDisabledStyle"
                    value="#{logPackageRequest.logPackageRequest.from}" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                    cellHeight="22px" inputStyle="width:180px" />
```

And I have this button :

```
            <a4j:commandButton id="Submit_button"
                value="#{msgs.submitButton}" styleClass="form_button"
                action="#{logPackageRequest.createLogPackageRequest}"
                reRender="clrForm,clearInactive_button"
                oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) #{rich:component('createLogRequestView')}.hide();" />
```

And I have this issue:

When I pressed the button it is called the function createLogPackageRequest.
But only if date is formated corect (like this 05/23/2013). If date is y5/23/2013 or uhnt3/2013 the function createLogPackageRequest is not called anymore.
Why is this strange behaviour? How can I fixed it?

Thanks,

Dorian

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not occurred if you set the value of `enableManualInput` attribute value as `false`, then every time you select the date from calendar.

You select the Date format as `MM/dd/yyyy` then why are enter the characters which are not relative to date.

**enableManualInput:** 
If "true" calendar input will be editable and it will be possible to change the date manualy. If "false" value for this attribute makes a text field "read-only", so the value can be changed only from a handle. Default value is "false".

Here is Example:

```
 <rich:calendar id="olr_from" enableManualInput="false" 
          isDayEnabled="isDayEnabled"
          dayStyleClass="getDisabledStyle"
          value="#{logPackageRequest.logPackageRequest.from}" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
          cellHeight="22px" inputStyle="width:180px" />
```